# Looking for a Title: Post-Apocalypse Dystopian Utah

Tags: story-identification

I recall reading it in the 1980's.  It was set in post-apocalypse Utah and revolved around a character who was an assassin operating under the cover of a search and rescue specialist. Any idea on the author/title?

Comment: There isn't much to go on here. Are there any other details you can remember? When you read it in the 80's, did it seem new at the time? Can we assume it was in English because of it being set in Utah? What agency did the assassin work for? Any idea what the cover looked like? Was it a short story or a novel?

Comment: Was it a novel or a short story? How could you tell it was Utah? Recognizable scenery, or town names, or what?

Comment: Long shot - Lia, human of Utah.

Comment: You ever find this answer? I'm trying to determine title/author of the same book... It's a novel, the assassin works for what is the new government of the US based in SLC, which encompasses as I recall most of the Western US, and is largely dominated by the LDS Church. It was an enjoyable read, but damned if I can recall the author or title.

Comment: I think that’s just Utah.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're talking about a trilogy by Dean Ing: *Systemic Shock*, *Single Combat* and *Wild Country*. The stories are set after a war that splintered the U.S. into various more-or-less independent countries. Utah is recovering faster than some of the other territories because of Mormon practices of self-sufficiency.

We see the protagonist, Ted Quantrill, growing from a teenager to a young man. Particularly in *Systemic Shock* we're introduced to the Search and Rescue team that doubles as a death squad, and a lot of the plot revolves around Quantrill's rebellion. Here's a link to a useful description from James Nicoll, which may provide additional supporting detail: ["one of my tinfoil hat theories"](https://jamesdavisnicoll.com/review/one-of-my-tinfoil-hat-theories/)

> Streamlined America is Mormon-dominated. Not only was living where the bombs didn’t fall the key to survival, but the Mormon practice of keeping a year’s worth of supplies gave them an edge. Many Gentiles converted after being saved by those supplies. President Young foresees a glorious future in which American policy is guided by the Quorum of the Twelve Apostles, led by none other than Young himself.
>
> The fact that this violates constitutional law does not bother Young, nor does the fact that most Mormons would object to his plan. Dubiously sane Young sees himself as a messianic figure. Fate has handed him the tools he needs: a battered America willing to set aside certain civil liberties during reconstruction, control of national media, and best of all, Section T, America’s own death squad.
>
> Section T’s assassins are loyal to the death. Literally: every killer carries a remote-controlled bomb in their head. Defection is a death sentence. The assassins of Section T are a bright, highly motivated group of survivors. None are brighter or more competent than Ted Quantrill. As Young will learn to his cost….

Comment: Good catch! Definitely a better match than mine. Were you familiar with the series, or did you find it via search? If the latter, what sort of search terms worked?

Comment: I was familiar with the series - I read the books when they were published. It helped that James Nicoll had fairly recently done a retrospective on them (as per the link). Thanks for improving my answer, by the way.

Comment: Not at all. You had a good answer as it was, but I figured quoting something from the link, in case it went bad at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Long shot, but is it possible you're thinking of *[Prayers for the Assassin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prayers_for_the_Assassin)* by Robert Ferrigno?

> The book starts off during the second American Civil War with a Muslim soldier dying in 2017, at the battle of Newark. Flash forward to the Super Bowl in 2042 in Seattle, the capital of the new Islamic Republic, the majority of whose inhabitants have converted to Islam. The nation's culture is a fusion of traditional American and Islamic: the Super Bowl is still played, but the cheerleaders are sword-wielding men and the participants break at half-time for afternoon prayers.
>
> As the story opens, the country is facing a crisis, with competing political and religious factions threatening to destroy the fragile peace that exists within the Islamic States of America. At the same time, behind the scenes, a messianic figure known as the Wise Old One contrives to seize power for himself, and fulfill the ancient prophecy of the restoration of the Caliphate.
>
> The story's protagonist is Rakkim Epps, a Muslim and ex-Fedayeen shadow warrior. Epps must risk everything to save the life of Sarah Dougan, the young historian he loves.
>
> It becomes known that it was in fact Muslim extremists who launched the attacks, including the dirty bomb in Mecca. A fourth, more powerful bomb (later found in China) was scheduled for detonation but the small group of Muslim extremists assigned the task succumbed to radiation poisoning before it could be put into play.
>
> Once the truth was exposed, the parties stepped back from the brink and sought to find a common ground from which to start a more trusting, more open-minded dialog. Thomas "Redbeard" Dougan, Sarah's uncle, dies in the aftermath.
>
> At the epilogue, Rakkim is in a mosque, performing his salat, or ritual prayer. There is a final showdown between Darwin, the "evil" assassin and Rakkim, with both of them almost dying. Rakkim finishes the showdown by killing Darwin with a knife throw to the face, but the rest of the ending sets up the conditions for the sequel.

Parts of the story are apparently set in Utah, which is part of the Mormon territories. However, it wasn't published until 2006.